# The trouble with member function pointers and template classes

Tags: c++

**TL;DR: Templatized events have an issues with subscription collisions and unsubscription.  The method of storing the data has made comparison difficult and casting from base to derived near impossible.**

I was attempting to refamiliarize myself with the basics of c++ after working c# for along time and to do so, I decided to write an event system that mimics the functionality of c#'s System.Action class.

So far I've written a functor class that contains a vector of templatized member functors, but the main issue I'm having is resolving collisions, and unsubscribing from the event.

My initial thoughts were to compare the memory address of the templatized member function pointers, however because the vector holds references to the base class, which does not depend on the member functions type, I'm having trouble accessing that data for comparison.

I was hoping that I could convert the member function's memory address to an integer and store that in the base class, but that kind of cast is illegal.

I have also thought of overloading the == operator in the derived class, but because of how things are templated the cast from base to derived seems impossible.

I did think of returning a reference to the iterator to solve the unsubscription issue, but that has a few problems. 1) The issue of duplicate subscription still remains. 2) [I'm not wholly certain if this is true] but it's possible that erasing an index from the vector would invalidate any iterators that the user has stored as handles to the subscribed functions.

I know a simple solution might be to use std::function to wrap these member functions and then compare std::function::target to the function I'm attempting to subscribe / unsubscribe to / from even. However the point of the exercise was to resolve this issue without using any of the utility classes that exist in the language.

Here is the header file for the event system so that you can get an idea of the architectural approach I was taking for the system.

```cpp
#include <vector>

template <class ...Args>
class EventDataBase
{
public:
    virtual void Invoke(Args ...arg) = NULL;
};

template<class T, class ...Args>
class EventData : public EventDataBase<Args...>
{
private:
    T *_instance;
    void (T::*_method)(Args ...arg);

public:
    EventData(T *instance, void (T::*method)(Args ...arg));
    void Invoke(Args ...arg);
};

template<class ...Args>
class Event
{
private:
    std::vector<EventDataBase<Args...>*> _subscribedReceivers;

public:
    template<class T>
    void Subscribe(T *instance, void (T::*method)(Args ...arg));
    template<class T>
    void Unsubscribe(void (T::*method)(Args ...arg));
    void Invoke(Args ...arg);
};
```

Comment: `TL;DR:` is a bold beginning, I'll give you that. - Remove all thing related to why you are here.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: "*the base class, which does not depend on the member functions type*" - huh? It totally depends on that type. What do you think `Args` is? "*... I'm having trouble accessing that data for comparison.*" What kind of trouble? What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: @melpomene "*the base class which does not dependon the member functions type*" - I'm talking about the `T` as in the class that the function is declared in. `...Args` is a parameter pack to account for the functions signature. 

If you read through the rest of the post I detail some things I tried in order to resolve the issues I'm having. (e.g. trying to cast base to derived and not being allowed to; trying to cast void (T::*method)(Args... arg) to an integer so I could have an integer representation of the function pointers memory address)